# .net how to set OAuth2 token length

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin-middleware

I am using

> Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions

to work with OAuth2 tokens.
currently the token length is  256 characters, my client want it to be only 36 characters.
is there a way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Shorten access token returned by OWIN in ASP.NET WebAPI 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067421/shorten-access-token-returned-by-owin-in-asp-net-webapi-2)

Comment: Hi, I saw this answer. He suggests bypassing this by using a dictionary.

Comment: Seems like this is the only option
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34067421/shorten-access-token-returned-by-owin-in-asp-net-webapi-2

Comment: When you say token, do you mean the access token for implicit flow or which flow are you talking about?

Comment: access token, tnx

Comment: Which format are you thinking for the Access Token? JWT is not an option with only 36 characters.

Comment: OAuth2 token,  or I miss something